# Monaca Onsen UI でタブバーを2段表示したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

Monaca Onsen UIでタブバーを2段にして表示することは可能でしょうか

Answer (score 1):

実装を見てみましたが、特に途中で段を変えるといった処理は入っていないようなので、
2段表示は難しいと思います。

こんな感じでした（一部抜粋）。

```
// tabbar itemのテンプレート
var defaultInnerTemplate =
    '<div ng-if="icon != undefined" class="tab-bar__icon">' +
      '<ons-icon icon="{{tabIcon}}"></ons-icon>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div ng-if="label" class="tab-bar__label">{{label}}</div>';

// tabbar item追加
compile: function(element, attrs) {
  element.addClass('tab-bar__item');

  return function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
    var tabbarView = element.inheritedData('ons-tabbar');
    if (!tabbarView) {
      throw new Error('This ons-tab element is must be child of ons-tabbar element.');
    }

    element.addClass(tabbarView._scope.modifierTemplater('tab-bar--*__item'));
    element.addClass(tabbarView._scope.modifierTemplater('tab-bar__item--*'));

    transclude(scope.$parent, function(cloned) {
      var wrapper = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.tab-bar-inner'));

      if (attrs.icon || attrs.label || !cloned[0]) {
        var innerElement = angular.element('<div>' + defaultInnerTemplate + '</div>').children();
        wrapper.append(innerElement);
        $compile(innerElement)(scope);
      } else {
        wrapper.append(cloned);
      }
    });
```